# Windows 10 license in VM (Hyper-V) won't activate

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 pro license on my computer. This is the free upgrade from Windows 7 so everything is legit here. Then I decided to install Hyper-V and install Windows 10 on it. I do that, install it, do all of the updates and now when I try to activate it I get this error message "We can't activate Windows on this device right now. You can try to activating again later or go tot he store to buy genuine Windows. Error code: 0x803FABBD"

I clicked on the troubleshoot link in the same page and it wont activate stating their was an unexpected error has occurred but I can click on the  "I changed hardware..." and the error I get is "We can

Finally I tried to search that error code on google and surprisingly I got nothing. So ya I this point I need help here. I was thinking perhaps its because its a free upgrade license and not the "genuine" one like on a sticker label for example.

Comment: Due to the error you have received you will have to contact the Microsoft Activation Center in order to activate the installation on the VM.  Before you do that, be sure you purchase a license for it and change the product key, otherwise even the Activation Center method won't work.

Comment: Like I said, the licence key is from a windows 7 pro. THen I upgraded to windows 10. From that point I installed hyperv and installed w10 on it so the key is good...technically

Comment: Right; You upgrade the Windows 7 license to Windows 10.  *You cannot use the license on the host operating system and the virtual machine.*  If you want to hear it from the horses mouth, call the Microsoft Activation Center, they will tell you exactly the samething.

Comment: ok so to be clear, I need the retail Windows 10 licence...not the upgrade since that one wont work. mhhhh ok

Comment: You need one licence for each machine you install Windows 10 on to (virtual or real).

Comment: ok.I'll have to do some research on that to get more information. Thank god I work in a pc store. I'm pretty sure I'll find another licence key. yay for that. Thanks for the information guys

Comment: @LateGameReviewer - Your welcome to use the license you received from the upgrade on the virtual machine by itself, but you can't use the same license, for both the host os and the guest os

Comment: @LateGameReviewer, first of all, welcome to Super User!  Please feel free to ask one of the contributors to post their input as an answer, or you can submit your own solution as the proposed answer after waiting for the 48-hour grace period.  However, we don't append a **(Solved)** suffix to the title of our questions.  When the time comes, an [Accepted Answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) will already stand out with a bright green box.  Thanks for your help!